# Clearing a Function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This may seem like a simple question. I've tried to Google the answer, but I can't seem to find it so that's why I'm here for help. Part of the problem is that I can't really phrase the question properly, so I will try to explain it here. Here goes...

I have two functions in my JavaScript file (let's name them `fn1()` and `fn2()`). I am calling these functions using `onclick` in my HTML file. For example:

```
<span class="test" onclick="fn1();">Button #1</span>
<span class="test" onclick="fn2();">Button #2</span>
```

The functions work perfectly fine  when a user clicks on their respective buttons. However, if a users clicks on Button #1, and then Button #2 - both functions are called/loaded simultaneously.

**Question**: How do I make it so that `fn1()` is disabled (or cleared) as soon as the user clicks on Button #2, which will load `fn2()`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery way the [noop method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noop/)

Within fn1() function you should use $.noop() to empty the function fn2()

Or simply as you are calling it on onclick you can remove that attribute within that function. (I don't recommend to use this)

```
$('span.test').not($(this)).removeAttr('onclick');
```

But I extremely recommend to use [namespace](http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/) by which you can unbind the click event like the following instead of calling inline javascript:

The [on method](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$( "span.test" ).on( "click.something", function( event ) {
//do your stuff here
});
```

Later you can unbind the click event like this:

The [off method](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

```
$("span.test").off("click.something");
```

Comment: A lot of suggestions here, but this one worked for me. Thanks! And I guess the phrase I was looking for "unbind the click event".

Answer (score 0):

The nice way: disable the `fn2` *button* when you enter `fn1` (rather than disabling the function). This also has a side effect of letting the user know that the button is not available. Disabled elements do not fire 'click' events.

```
$('span.test').not($(this)).prop('disable', true);
```

The not-so-nice-way: set a variable when you're in one function, and clear it when you exit. Return early from the functions if the variable is set.

The downright ugly way: unbind the onclick from the other buttons if one is clicked. This is so messy that you really don't want to do that.

The I-really-can't-recommend-it-less way: redefine the other functions with no-ops.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand your question correctly and I don't have enough rep to comment
but if you want the user not to be able to press the second button until the first finishes execution then you could do the follwing

in the first line of your fn2() add the following line

```
document.getElementById("button1").disabled = true
```

but you should first give an id `button1` to the first button

this will grey the button `button1` when the user press the button

after your code finishes execution you should add:

```
document.getElementById("button1").disabled = false
```

this will make the button pressable again

Answer (score 0):

u may try this with flags, this is not going to clear the function e.g.:

```
var runFn1 = true;

function fn1() {
  if (!runFn1) {
    return;
  }
  // ur code here
}

function fn2() {
  runFn1 = false;
  // ur code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"The functions work perfectly fine when a user clicks on their respective buttons. However, if a users clicks on Button #1, and then Button #2 - both functions are called/loaded simultaneously."

javascript being single threaded. fn1() execution is first completed and then followed by fn2(). Hope you understand there will not be a case where both are called simultaneously.

For example

```
function fn1(){
    while(true){
    }
}

function fn2(){
    alert("2");
}
<input type="button" value="Btn1" onClick="fn1();"/>
<input type="button" value="Btn2" onClick="fn2();"/>
```

Try invoking fn1(). you will be surprised fn2() cannot be invoked!